# Figuring out item value in Dwarf Fortress Adventure

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-adventure

I am playing Dwarf Fortress Adventure mode, I've run out of food so I need to trade at a town. When I open a trader's shop menu I can't see any price indication like in fortress mode, only item weight (Possibly a skill I need to put ranks in?) .

I am trying to trade water from the town well, but I can't figure out how much water to trade for yams and the town has no currency afaik.

**Is there any way of telling how much an item is worth or is there a chart/reference I can use?**

Comment: I'm not very well versed in adventure mode, but it would only be reasonable to have a very high barter-related skill to be able to sell people's own water to them.

Comment: Actually no; you get the water from the well, it's yours. Oddly enough he's happy to trade it straight from my backpack despite the fact he has no container to put it in. :)

Comment: Well, I really can't comment on that in any way besides "Dorfs are stupid".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you can't see the real value of the items while trading you can, through trial and error, figure out their approximate value. Unlike trading in DF Fortress mode, in DF adventure mode the traders don't get mad at you if you offer too little; they will just refuse that trade. This means that you can offer a too small amount for their items and when they refuse that trade just repeat with a larger trade offer until your trade is enough that they are willing to take it. This info is per the [DF Wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Adventurer_mode#Trading_.28barter.29).

Comment: Oh really? That's good to know, I just assumed that they'd get mad if I kept making offers.

Comment: I made the same assumption until I read the WIKI page. I know Toady (the creator of DF) is trying to integrate both DF Fortress and DF Adventure modes, so I sort of figured that trading with merchants would work the same way in both.